# What is the receiver component in Snap Circuits part U24 (Infrared Receiver)?

Tags: sensor, datasheet, infrared

I'm trying to find a datasheet for the receiver component in Snap Circuits part **U24**, which is an infrared light detector/receiver. It looks exactly like a TSOP382 sensor (picture below) but doesn't seem to work like one.

[image: TSOP38238 sensor]

Here's my understanding of how the component works:

- Similar to an NPN transistor
- Connect pin 1 to Vcc (5V)
- Connect pin 2 to GND (0V) (similar to Emitter)
- Connect load to pin 3 (LED in my case) (similar to Collector)
- When infrared light is detected, pin 3 and pin 2 are connected, like in an NPN transistor

Again, I'm specifically looking for the datasheet or the exact name of the component.

Comment: It sounds like a pretty normal phototransistor?

Comment: I think so but I need the datasheet and therefore the name of the component.

Comment: You're going to have trouble if you want the exact part number. This sounds like an extremely generic part.

Comment: Yeah, I feared that.

Comment: If it **IS a TSOP38238** , then you should be able to measure a resistance of roughly 30k ohm between the two outside pins...this is the pullup resistor between *output pin* and *Vcc pin*. Do this check with no power applied, and verify by measuring with ohmmeter probes swapped.

Comment: @glen_geek I tried that and I'm reading 34.3k ohms. I think it might be a TSOP382. When reading the description of the TSOP382, it did not seem like a phototransistor. When looking at a schematic using it, it was used like one. What I have is a phototransistor, and measures 34.3k ohms, so you're correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like an infra-red receiver that's used for TV "remotes". These universally are encapsulated in black plastic that blocks visible light, but is transparent to infra-red light. These are far more complicated than a photo-transistor.

- Two pins accept DC power between 3V and 5V.
- A third pin is a digital output.

[image: ir remote pinout]
[image: IR remote internal block diagram]

Most infrared receiver chips contain a pullup resistor between digital output pin and DC supply pin - roughly 30k ohms. This can be probed with an ohmmeter. It is unlikely that a phototransistor would measure 30k ohms between two pins, especially if you reversed the ohmmeter leads, and *still* measured 30k.

Your posted photo looks like a **TSOP38238** , made by VISHAY.  Vishay provides data sheets.
Its digital output pin pulls low only when it receives short bursts of 38kHz-modulated infrared light, such as that produced by many TV remote transmitters. Steadily shining infrared light at it produces no output (output remains "high").